# Using AND in Switch Expression in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

Below is my code I use in the Color `Expression` in `SSRS 2008` to change the color of the text.

```
=Switch(Fields!DistanceFromOutlet.Value > 500, "Red",
Fields!DistanceFromOutlet.Value < 250, "White")
```

How would I say if the DistanceFromOutlet.Value > 250 and < 500 it must be Orange?

So **Red** text for more than `500`.

**Orange** text for betweeen `250` and `500`.

And **White** text for less than `250`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nest two `IIf`s:

```
=IIf(Fields!DistanceFromOutlet.Value > 500, "Red", IIf(Fields!DistanceFromOutlet.Value < 250, "White", "Orange"))
```

Comment: Good answer, but @Davos' is much more efficient

Answer (score 5):

The Switch function is evaluated from left to right so you can do this:

```
=Switch(Fields!DistanceFromOutlet.Value <=250, "White", Fields!DistanceFromOutlet.Value <= 500, "Orange", Fields!DistanceFromOutlet.Value > 500, "Red")
```

What I suspect is that you tried to do this which does not work:

```
Fields!DistanceFromOutlet.Value > 250 and < 500
```

That would work if you changed it to be explicit:

```
Fields!DistanceFromOutlet.Value > 250 and Fields!DistanceFromOutlet.Value < 500
```